# Print window without print popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I want to print a page without window.print() popup. How can i do it?
There is anyway about that? I want to programmatically  print a document but i don't find anything about that.

I dont want code block like this.

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById('main');
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=650,scrollbars=1,menuBar=1');
var str =  prtContent.innerHTML;
WinPrint.document.write(str);
WinPrint.document.print();
```

Comment: From a browser you have to use the print popup

Comment: I don't want to use it.

Comment: It would be a security issue i guess...

Comment: Well that is your only way, otherwise any website could randomly print anything they wanted

Comment: that's what you have...

Comment: Ink manufactures would love if you didn't have to.

Comment: if i understand correctly you are just trying to print a whole page.
check this. [window.print](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print)

Comment: i can bypass print preview window in firefox successfully, dont know other browser supports http://ccm.net/faq/16248-firefox-disable-printing-from-the-preview-window

Comment: @arunkumar that is a user setting you would have to tell each user to do that, you can't set that setting programmatically

Comment: Now i have a printer of zebra. I printing two paper on one page. I think the printer going to print my page asynchronous . Its a issue about me . I want to print them on a Queue